# Is PAA a good candidate for automating wcm library deployment and setup in portal?

Tags: websphere-portal

I have created a `Web Content Management` library for use in `WebSphere Portal`. At the moment I'm using `import-wcm-data` to import the library, then I need to add some additional propeties to 2-3 files on the server under `Resource Environment Providers` and then restart particular services so those changes are detected.

Can anyone explain the benefits of using a `paa` over writing a simple `bash` (or similar) script to automate this process?

I don't understand if I get any advantages when using `paa`, or is `paa` even capable of updating properties files and restarting services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working intensively with PAA files and I must say that it is a very stable way of deploying a app requirering multiple depl steps and components.
It does need a startup process but is well worth it in a multi server environment.
You can do all the tasks that you can do in a Ant file as well as using the wsadmin script interface. I only update res env settings and the such in WAS and do not touch any props files for that reason since all settings are stored in WAS.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a PAA is not a good method if you're merely importing a content library.

I don't think I understand why you are doing the import manually and not syndicating, but even if there's a good reason not to syndicate, the PAA process was too involved and required too many precursor actions (deleting libraries, remove PAA, deploy PAA and then activate the portliest) to be a viable option for something as simple as importing a WCM library.

Since activating the portlets I was importing with the PAA was an extra step, I don't believe you can restart applications either.